# Website still trying to call js files from uninstalled plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm using GTmetrix (waterfall section) to troubleshoot a slow-loading Wordpress site, and it's showing that several .js files associated with the plugin that I have uninstalled/deleted are still loading - or trying to load. The plugin files are no longer on the server. When i navigate trough the Waterfall chart i can see the js files associated to the plugin. The calls are red and show 0 kb. But my website is still trying to call these files. 
I've seen some suggestions to try and solve this such as looking at options.php to see if the plugin still had left something behind because of bad coding/writing. But my options.php file shows no leftovers from the particular plugin (accordion FAQ, formerly known as responsive accordion and collapse)

Why would my website still try to call these js files from plugins that have already been deleted?

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins enabled on your site. If a caching plugin is active and you haven't purged the cache, these files will still be called.

Comment: Hi, yes i do use a caching plugin (WP fastest cache). I have only used the delete cache option. I have not tried the delete cache + minified css/js option. But isnt minified css/js what i actually want to have. As i recall minified js and css actually reduces file size.

Comment: Delete the Cache Folder in wp-content

Comment: Clearing your cache doesn't mean the plugin won't re-cache the latest content.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so as an answer :) Are you using a caching plugin? You could be looking at cache. If so, purge all cache (always an option somewhere in the caching plugin).

Comment: Hi, yes i do use a caching plugin (WP fastest cache). I have only used the delete cache option. I have not tried the delete cache + minified css/js option.
But isnt minified css/js what i actually want to have. As i recall minified js and css actually reduces file size.

Comment: Yes, you want to have the minified css/js... but, if the current cached minified css/js still contain references to the now non-existing files, I would try to delete the cache. It will be rebuild after page visit.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cache + minified css/js option in WP fastest cache was what worked for me.